# Can I corrupt the Boss' team?

Tags: dusk-city-outlaws

It's the final scene, a minor villain has appeared to wreck the getaway, and I, in my role as "Judge" (GM), want a few of the "Boss'" crew member's minions to "cross the aisle" and side with the villain.

What do I require to do this? Can I do it with heat, or do I need them to roll disadvantage dice? Or does the rule that "they must always work as a single unit" mean I can't co-opt them?

And if so, can I do it by "retroactively" taking them out and introducing minions to replace them?

Answer (score 2):

In the Judge's Rulebook, it notes that having an ally of the group reveal itself to be working against the characters in secret is a Plot Twist complication that costs 20 Heat. (p.9) If that seems too expensive, you could combine two minor complications — Escalate an Obstacle and Reinforcements — for a total of 8 heat. Either way, it's definitely something you can do with Heat, especially in the final scene.